# Admin form edits not saving to the right id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, forms, mongoose, handlebars.js

#### The Problem

So I have an application that has admins and there able to edit all user forms. However when I go to edit a user form it doesn't seem to use the users id that's being edited it's using the id of the admin that's signed in.

So when I edit a user form, it's editing the admins forms and not the user form.

For example:

I have two users

Admin:: 5a735764cd571d23319a8c31 <-- admin account

User one:: 5a73580acd571d23319a8c32

and lets say I go to edit user one's competition form

The url here is

http://localhost:3000/dashboard/users/forms/competition-form/5a73580acd571d23319a8c32

The url is correctly using the user one's id however when I make a change on user one's form. The admin form gets changed only and not admin user.

Here are some logs

```
Mongoose: users.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("5a735764cd571d23319a8c31") }, { fields: {} })
Fri Feb 02 2018 16:46:11 GMT+0000 (GMT): GET /dashboard/users/forms/competition-form/edit/5a73580acd571d23319a8c32
Mongoose: competitionforms.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("5a73580acd571d23319a8c32") }, { fields: {} })

Fri Feb 02 2018 16:46:11 GMT+0000 (GMT): GET /favicon.ico
Mongoose: users.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("5a735764cd571d23319a8c31") }, { fields: {} })
Fri Feb 02 2018 16:46:20 GMT+0000 (GMT): POST /dashboard/users/forms/competition-form/5a735764cd571d23319a8c31
Mongoose: competitionforms.findAndModify({ _id: ObjectId("5a735764cd571d23319a8c31") }, [], { '$setOnInsert': { __v: 0 }, '$set': { schoolName: 'Haybridge', competitionDate: '02/14/2018', competitionTime: '10:30 AM', compe
titionVenue: 'Haybridge High', competitionTotalOfStudents: 10, competitionTotalParticipated: 7, competitionTotalPersonnel: 7, competitionJudge1Name: 'Ben Bagley', competitionJudge1Telephone: '7476440096', competitionJudge1
Email: 'ben@benbagley.co.uk', competitionJudge2Name: 'Moss Moss', competitionJudge2Telephone: '7476440096', competitionJudge2Email: 'ben@benbagley.co.uk', competitionJudge3Name: 'Jen Barber', competitionJudge3Telephone: '7
476440096', competitionJudge3Email: 'ben@benbagley.co.uk' } }, { upsert: true, new: false, remove: false, fields: {} })
{ schoolName: 'Haybridge',
  competitionDate: '02/14/2018',
  competitionTime: '10:30 AM',
  competitionVenue: 'Haybridge High',
  competitionTotalOfStudents: '10',
  competitionTotalParticipated: '7',
  competitionTotalPersonnel: '7',
  competitionJudge1Name: 'Ben Bagley',
  competitionJudge1Telephone: '7476440096',
  competitionJudge1Email: 'ben@benbagley.co.uk',
  competitionJudge2Name: 'Moss Moss',
  competitionJudge2Telephone: '7476440096',
  competitionJudge2Email: 'ben@benbagley.co.uk',
  competitionJudge3Name: 'Jen Barber',
  competitionJudge3Telephone: '7476440096',
  competitionJudge3Email: 'ben@benbagley.co.uk' }
Mongoose: users.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("5a735764cd571d23319a8c31") }, { fields: {} })
Fri Feb 02 2018 16:46:20 GMT+0000 (GMT): GET /dashboard
```

See how the database seems to fetch the Admin user and not user one.

#### Down to the code

routes.js

```
// Competition Form
// competition form details
router.get('/dashboard/users/forms/competition-form/:id', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  CompetitionForm.findById(req.params.id, function(err, competition){
    res.render('dashboard/users/forms/competition-form.hbs', {
      pageTitle: 'Competition Form',
      competitions: competition
    });
  });
});

// competition form details post
router.post('/dashboard/users/forms/competition-form/:id', (req, res) => {
  CompetitionForm.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id }, req.body, {upsert:true}, (err, competition) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(`Error saving data:  ${err}`);
      return res.send('Error saving data');
    }

    res.redirect('/dashboard');
    console.log(req.body);
  });
});
```

competition-form.hbs

```
{{> header}}

<div class="container">
  {{#if user.admin}}
  <form action="/dashboard/users/forms/competition-form/{{user.id}}" method="post">
    <h2>Edit School Competition Form</h2>
    <p>
      <b>All fields with <span style="color: red">*</span> are required</b>
    </p>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        General Information
      </div>

      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label for="schoolName">
              School Name <span style="color: red">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="schoolName" placeholder="Enter school name" value="{{competitions.schoolName}}" required>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-6 date" data-provide="datepicker">
            <label for="competitionDate">
              Competition Date <span style="color: red">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="competitionDate" name="competitionDate" placeholder="Enter the date of competition" value="{{competitions.competitionDate}}" required>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="competitionTime">
              Time <span style="color: red">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="competitionTime" name="competitionTime" placeholder="Enter the time of the competition (e.g. 8:00 AM)" value="{{competitions.competitionTime}}" required>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label for="competitionVenue">
              Venue <span style="color: red">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="competitionVenue" name="competitionVenue" placeholder="Enter where the competition was held" value="{{competitions.competitionVenue}}" required>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="competitionTotalOfStudents">
              Total number of students in the program <span style="color: red">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="competitionTotalOfStudents" name="competitionTotalOfStudents" placeholder="Enter the total number" value="{{competitions.competitionTotalOfStudents}}" required>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="competitionTotalParticipated">
              Total number of students that participated <span style="color: red">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="competitionTotalParticipated" name="competitionTotalParticipated" placeholder="Enter the total number" value="{{competitions.competitionTotalParticipated}}" required>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="competitionTotalPersonnel">
              Total number of school personnel involved in the program <span style="color: red">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="competitionTotalPersonnel" name="competitionTotalPersonnel" placeholder="Enter the total number" value="{{competitions.competitionTotalPersonnel}}" required>
          </div>
        </div><!-- row ends -->
      </div><!-- End of panel body -->
    </div><!-- School Information panel ends -->

    <!-- Judge 1 Info -->
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        Judge 1
      </div>

      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label for="competitionJudge1Name">
              Judge's Name <span style="color: red">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="competitionJudge1Name" name="competitionJudge1Name" placeholder="Enter the Judge's Name" value="{{competitions.competitionJudge1Name}}" required>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="competitionJudge1Telephone">
              Telephone <span style="color: red">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="competitionJudge1Telephone" name="competitionJudge1Telephone" placeholder="Enter the Judge's Telephone Number" value="{{competitions.competitionJudge1Telephone}}" required>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="competitionJudge1Email">
              Email address <span style="color: red">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="competitionJudge1Email" name="competitionJudge1Email" placeholder="judge@example.com" value="{{competitions.competitionJudge1Email}}" required>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- end of row -->
    </div>

    <!-- Judge 2 Info -->
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        Judge 2
      </div>

      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label for="competitionJudge2Name">
              Judge's Name <span style="color: red">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="competitionJudge2Name" name="competitionJudge2Name" placeholder="Enter the Judge's Name" value="{{competitions.competitionJudge2Name}}" required>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="competitionJudge2Telephone">
              Telephone <span style="color: red">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="competitionJudge2Telephone" name="competitionJudge2Telephone" placeholder="Enter the Judge's Telephone Number" value="{{competitions.competitionJudge2Telephone}}" required>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="competitionJudge2Email">
              Email address <span style="color: red">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="competitionJudge2Email" name="competitionJudge2Email" placeholder="judge@example.com" value="{{competitions.competitionJudge2Email}}" required>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- end of row -->
    </div>

    <!-- Judge 3 Info -->
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        Judge 3
      </div>

      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label for="competitionJudge3Name">
              Judge's Name <span style="color: red">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="competitionJudge3Name" name="competitionJudge3Name" placeholder="Enter the Judge's Name" value="{{competitions.competitionJudge3Name}}" required>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="competitionJudge3Telephone">
              Telephone <span style="color: red">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="competitionJudge3Telephone" name="competitionJudge3Telephone" placeholder="Enter the Judge's Telephone Number" value="{{competitions.competitionJudge3Telephone}}" required>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="competitionJudge3Email">
              Email address <span style="color: red">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="competitionJudge3Email" name="competitionJudge3Email" placeholder="judge@example.com" value="{{competitions.competitionJudge3Email}}" required>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- end of row -->
    </div>

    <!-- The following fields are hidden to users and should ONLY be visible and editable by a site admin-level user. -->
    <div class="panel panel-danger">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        Administrators Only
      </div>

      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>Sent Required Photos? (currently {{competitions.competitionRequiredPhotos}})</p>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="competitionRequiredPhotos" id="yesPhotosRadio" value="yes">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="yesPhotosRadio">Yes</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="competitionRequiredPhotos" id="noPhotosRadio" value="no">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="noPhotosRadio">No</label>
        </div>

        <p>Sent Required Certifications? (currently {{competitions.competitionRequiredCertifications}})</p>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="competitionRequiredCertifications" id="yesCertsRadio" value="yes">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="yesCertsRadio">Yes</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="competitionRequiredCertifications" id="noCertsRadio" value="no">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="noCertsRadio">No</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End of fields hidden to user -->

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
  {{else}}
  <div class="text-center">
    <h3>This is not the page you are looking for.</h3>
    <p>Only admins have access to this page.</p>
  </div>
  {{/if}}
</div>

{{> footer}
```

#### What I expect

I want admins to be able to update user forms and informations with no issues, so fetching the correct ID is critical.

This has been racking my brain for the past few days.

Help.

#### Edit 1

```
Mongoose: users.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("5a735764cd571d23319a8c31") }, { fields: {} }) **<--- logged in, admin id. This is correct**
Mon Feb 05 2018 13:36:33 GMT+0000 (GMT): GET /dashboard/users/5a73580acd571d23319a8c32/progress
Mongoose: users.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("5a73580acd571d23319a8c32") }, { fields: {} }) **<--- This is clicking on the `user` account, this is correct**
Mon Feb 05 2018 13:36:33 GMT+0000 (GMT): GET /favicon.ico
Mongoose: users.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("5a735764cd571d23319a8c31") }, { fields: {} }) **<--- this is the form being loaded, this is loading the admin and not the user, this is incorrect**
Mon Feb 05 2018 13:36:38 GMT+0000 (GMT): GET /dashboard/users/forms/competition-form/5a73580acd571d23319a8c32
Mongoose: competitionforms.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("5a73580acd571d23319a8c32") }, { fields: {} }) **<--- it now switches to the user id, but when in POST the admin id gets passed and not the user**
Mon Feb 05 2018 13:36:38 GMT+0000 (GMT): GET /favicon.ico
```

A you can see by the logs the admin id is getting passed not the user but the id's are switching.

Comment: In your line, CompetitionForm.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id }..., what is the value of req.params.id when it fails?

Comment: The user id shouldn't fail @JeffMatthews before going to the forms the admin has to click on the user then click on the user forms. I just don't see how the incorrect id is passing.

Comment: You say it "shouldn't" fail.  Did you confirm by looking at it?  What's the value?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is likely here:

```
<form action="/dashboard/users/forms/competition-form/{{user.id}}" method="post">
```

You're using handlebars.  I bet you `{{user.id}}` is not actually the user form you're editing, but the ID of the user currently logged in.  This is "usually" set from authentication via jwt and what not.  At any rate, that `user.id` is posting the admin ID, which simply gets posted down into the call to Mongo.

Edit:  Looking a bit more, all you're doing is rendering forms based on if the user logged in is an admin.  From this line:

```
{{#if user.admin}}
```

So it then builds an HTML form, and you're sending that ADMIN user.id, not the ID of some other user.  You need to add some code to specify "which user" you're editing, and pass that ID into the POST url instead.

Comment: In order to access the form I can use `<a href="/dashboard/users/forms/competition-form/{{users.id}}">` and it goes to that users form, but post doesn't seem to work the same way.

Comment: But what I'm saying is that whatever forms you're rending, is that of some administrator.  You're posting the admin ID through that POST action, and not the ID of another user.

Comment: Ok so what would you recommend?

Comment: Well, the issue isn't with routes or your database or anything.  It's all front-end.  You need to identify the correct way to populate the correct POST url from your HTML form you're generating.  In other words, you could go temporarily hard-code that POST action with the actual user id, and it would work.  You need to resolve who `user.id` truly is.